# How do I Unzip a 7z zip file using VBA

Tags: vba, navbar, vba7, vba6

I have a 7z .zip file I am trying to unzip with VBA. I have attempted several methods but to no avail.
See below the zip file type just to be sure where the problem could be from:
[Image of 7z file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVEx2.png)

I try the below code, it runs, downloads every attachment but does not unzip the zip file.

```
Dim ValidExtensions As Collection
Set ValidExtensions = New Collection

ValidExtensions.Add "csv"
ValidExtensions.Add "txt"
ValidExtensions.Add "xls"
ValidExtensions.Add "7z"
ValidExtensions.Add "zip"

Debug.Print "Checking attachments"

For Each objAttachment In objItem.Attachments
    Debug.Print "Found attachment: " & objAttachment.fileName

    Dim extension As String
    extension = LCase(Split(objAttachment.fileName, ".")(UBound(Split(objAttachment.fileName, "."))))
    Debug.Print "Extension: " & extension

    Dim isValidExtension As Boolean
    isValidExtension = False

    Dim validExtension As Variant
    For Each validExtension In ValidExtensions
        If extension = validExtension Then
            isValidExtension = True
            Debug.Print "Valid extension found"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next validExtension

    If isValidExtension Then
        Dim savedFilePath As String
        savedFilePath = monthFolder & "\" & objAttachment.fileName
        Debug.Print "Saving file to: " & savedFilePath
        objAttachment.SaveAsFile savedFilePath
        If extension = "7z" Then
            Debug.Print "7z file found, attempting to unzip"
            Dim pathTo7Zip As String
            pathTo7Zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe
            Dim command As String
            command = """" & pathTo7Zip & """ e """ & savedFilePath & """ -o""" & monthFolder & """ -y"
            Debug.Print "Running command: " & command
     
            Call shell(command)
        End If
    End If
Next objAttachment
```

In the immediate window, I get the below details,

```txt
Checking attachments
Found attachment: image001.jpg
Extension: jpg
Found attachment: mon_PROD.csv
Extension: csv
Valid extension found
Saving file to: C:\Users\Desktop\\mon_PROD.csv
Checking attachments
Found attachment: ZIP_mon_PROD.zip
Extension: zipChecking attachments
Found attachment: image001.jpg
Extension: jpg
Found attachment: mon_PROD.csv
Extension: csv
Valid extension found
Saving file to: C:\Users\Desktop\\mon_PROD.csv
Checking attachments
Found attachment: mon_PROD.zip
Extension: zip
Valid extension found
Saving file to: C:\Users\Desktop\\mon_PROD.zip
Valid extension found
Saving file to: C:\Users\Desktop\\mon_PROD.zip
```

I have been on this for hours and no headways.
Kindly assist.

Thanks.

Comment: `7zFM.exe` is the GUI, try just plain `7z.exe`

Comment: A quotation mark at the end of pathTo7Zip= ?

Comment: A missing quotation mark on pathTo7Zip, 7z.exe is the command line application, you can try cmd with `x` instead of `e`.

`pathTo7Zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

command = """" & pathTo7Zip & """ x """ & savedFilePath & """ -o""" & monthFolder & """ -y"`

Comment: `If extension = "7z" Then` isn't the file extension "zip" and not "7z" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting commands isn't hard but also can be a pain so he following might help, its a little like `printf` in other languages.

It takes a template string and substitutes values, and replaces `&quote;` with the quotes.

```
Function CommandBuild(ParamArray args() As Variant) As String
If IsMissing(args) Then CommandBuild = vbNullString: Exit Function

Dim Result As String
Dim Index As Integer
Dim UB As Integer: UB = UBound(args)
Dim Count As Integer: Count = UB - LBound(args)

Result = args(0)

If Count > 0 Then
    For Index = 1 To UB
        Result = Replace(Result, "{" & (Index - 1) & "}", args(Index))
    Next
End If

CommandBuild = Replace(Result, "&quote;", Chr(34))

End Function

Sub Example()

Dim pathTo7Zip As String: pathTo7Zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
Dim saveFilePath As String: saveFilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Month\file.7z"
Dim monthFolder As String: monthFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\Month"

Debug.Print CommandBuild("&quote;{0}&quote; e &quote;{1}&quote; -o &quote;{2}&quote; -y", pathTo7Zip, saveFilePath, monthFolder)

End Sub
```